# DateTime stamp not reading correctly as string

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

```py
        import pandas as pd
        import json
        import urllib.request
        from time import time, sleep
        from datetime import datetime


        #
        #
        # Still need to add DateTime stamp to each entry and save DataFrame to csv file with self                         updating name
        #
        #

        # This only works for API's that return a string formatted like a dictionary


        # ticker_url is the link to your market 
        # y_seconds is how many seconds code waits before running again. Typically API requests are limited in this
        # case it is limited to 1 time per second 
        # 
        # You may need to adjust your column names You can check column name by uncommenting and running this code below
        #
        # ticker_url = 'https://api.bittrex.com/v3/markets/btc-usdt/ticker'
        # with urllib.request.urlopen(ticker_url) as response:
        #      html = response.read()

        ticker_url = 'https://api.bittrex.com/v3/markets/btc-usdt/ticker'
        interval_in_hours = .01
        end_time = time() + interval_in_hours * 3600
        y_seconds = 1
        ticker_list = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Symbol' , 'Last Trade', 'Bid' , 'Ask'])

        while time() < end_time:

            with urllib.request.urlopen(ticker_url) as response:
               html = response.read()

            ticker_data = json.loads(html)
            ticker_list = ticker_list.append(ticker_data , ignore_index=True)
            sleep(y_seconds)

        ticker_list.to_csv('market_data'+str(datetime.timestamp)+'.csv')
```

I have a couple notes to myself for the editing process but the main issue I am running into now is formatting the final line here:

```py
        ticker_list.to_csv('market_data'+str(datetime.timestamp)+'.csv')
```

This code has created this file

```
        market_data<method 'timestamp' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>.csv
```

I would like for it to read market_data20191130133030

for November 30 2019 1:30 PM and 30 seconds. I want the time stamp to read the time of file creation.

Can anyone help me fix this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime.timestamp()` is a [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp).  Thus change the line you called out to:

```py
ticker_list.to_csv('market_data'+str(datetime.timestamp())+'.csv')
```

However, `datetime.timestamp()` returns the POSIX timestamp (number of seconds since January 1, 1970). If you want a timestamp in the format of YYYYMMDDHHMMSS, then you'll need to use `datetime.strftime(format)`.  The format you will use is `%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.

Comment: Thank you for adjusting my attempt pattern. I tried as you suggested but it asked for me to pass an argument which I did not have. I switched from timestamp() to today() and was able to solve my problem! Thank you for your quick response!!